# How do I go into all text files in a directory and delete everything in them after the second space?

Tags: python, powershell

I have a directory like this:
[image: All text files]

Each text file has this information:

```
106 114 24 25 1 0
705 79 19 21 1 0
661 361 30 37 1 0
212 332 30 37 1 0
704 236 20 25 1 0
620 404 30 37 1 0
615 248 20 25 1 0
641 165 20 25 1 0
676 47 19 21 1 0
```

I am trying to write a script (windows 11) that goes into this directory, accesses each text file and deletes everything after the second space.

Basically, I want the new text files to be like this:

```
106 114
705 79
661 361
212 332
704 236
620 404
615 248
641 165
676 47
```

The script can be in python as well

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: You could do this with `grep` or `sed`, no programming required.

Comment: I had no idea about grep or sed, I am a bit new to this. I will definitely try them out, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import os

directory = '/path/to/directory'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'r+') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            file.seek(0)
            for line in lines:
                words = line.split()
                new_line = ' '.join(words[:2]) + '\n'
                file.write(new_line)
            file.truncate()
```

Replace /path/to/directory with the path to your directory

Comment: Thank you so much! I will accept this as an answer in 5 minutes!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import os

DIR = '/path'

for listed_file in os.listdir(DIR):
    if listed_file.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(listed_file, 'r') as file:
            final_lines = []
            for line in file.readlines():
                new_line = " ".join(line.split()[:2]) + "\n"
                final_lines.append(new_line)
        file = open(listed_file, 'w')
        file.writelines(final_lines)
```

it will run through each and every file in `DIR`, check if it is a txt file and then get its lines and rewrite it with the new split lines.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell version:

```
Get-ChildItem .\*.txt |Foreach-Object {
    (Select-String -LiteralPath $_ -Pattern '^\S+\s\S*').Matches |
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $_
}
```